# RL-Coach - how to use custom presets?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm trying to run a new [*OpenAI Gym*](https://gym.openai.com/) environment with [*Reinforcement Learning Coach*](https://github.com/NervanaSystems/coach) - how can I do that without having to copy my preset file to `.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/rl_coach/presets/` directory?

Say I've got `myenv_presets.py` file in my home directory and try to run coach:

```
~/coach $ coach -p myenv_presets
The given preset (myenv_presets:graph_manager) cannot be found.
```

However when I link the file to `.../site-packages/rl_coach/presets/myenv_presets.py` I can run the above no problems.

Is there any way to use a presets file from a working directory?

Answer (score 0):

Try running it with the full path to the preset file:

```
~/coach $ coach -p ~/coach/myenv_presets.py
```